# Rendering bug in Stack Exchange app for Android

Tags: bug, android-app

When I up vote, sometimes the text is rendered over the toolbar and status bar. See screen capture for an example.

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: VS425PP
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (161331805d4f5)